# Past 5 week calculation in WEBI (BO 4.0)?

Tags: business-objects

I am facing issue in **calculating past 5 week data based on current date** (excluding currrent week)
For e.g: 
Suppose we are in 40th week of this year, I need to get the sum of all the transactions for the previous 5 weeks (39, 38, 37, 36 & 35).

Currently calculating based on the calendar day but as Calendar day is giving the granular level of data, inorder to increase the performance ***I need to use the calendar week*** (sample data like (2012/40).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: looking for a solution based on the CalendarWeek

Answer (score 1):

I'd construct a flag field (either in the back-end or in the universe) using datediff (in SQL Server terms).

Failing that, you could construct a variable in Web Intelligence using the **Week** function.

Pseudo-code but something like:

```
=IF(Transaction_Date < Week(CurrentDate()) AND Transaction_Date >= (Week(CurrentDate())-5); "TRUE"; "FALSE")
```

Comment: suppose in my scenario i am getting rolling past 12 month data. Suppose we are in the 5th week of current year so for getting the past  5 week data, need to sum up the following week's data i.e 4th week,3rd week,2nd week, 1st week of 2012 and max week of last year (2011)

Comment: Also in BO 4.0 webi there is no option for WeekAdd

Comment: Then use a DATEDIFF style function in the back-end or universe which will allow you to subtract a number of weeks from a date even if you span years.